# QGIS - Zonal Statistics Batch - empty

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics, batch

after using zonal statistics by hand which works perfectly fine.
I want to use it in Batch-mode to extract Mean/SD/Median for different rasters in the same polygon. I can not select a rasterband, there is no option.

Unfortunately the output is empty, see below.

If anyone can help me would be great.

[image: Setup:]
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to select a valid raster channel as `Band Number`.
The logs show that `RASTER_BAND` is not valid:

[image]

If there is no option to select the raster band, I would analyse the input file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did not look at the logs! 

I created the input file in SNAP and it produces .img and .hdr, maybe I should save it as geotiff and see if this helps!

Comment: I tried it again using a GeoTiff, Still no Raster_Band selectable.

Comment: would you mind uploading the file somewhere, if it is not a private/classified one?